# Why is pthread_cond_wait a big portion of total perf samples in my program?

Tags: pthreads, boost-asio, perf

I use perf to do performance profiling, and get the following flame graph. Notice that a big portion of the total samples is `pthread_cond_wait`. I used `boost::asio` but not sure where is `pthread_cond_wait` is called. Can anyone give me some clue why this is happening. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means you have a lot of lock contention. Without code there's little useful we can say, except generalities:

- keep locks short
- use atomics where possible
- minimize resource sharing, so there is less need for synchronization of any kind, locking or otherwise
- e.g. moving resources with their tasks is a good pattern to remove sharing
- you might have too many threads; above a point you risk performance degradation due to increased lock contention

Going from the flame-graph alone I will add the tip that it is possible to optimize Asio in the case of single threaded application. See [Concurrency Hint](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/concurrency_hint.html).